# AngularJS Access bindings in Template Function

Tags: angularjs, binding, scope, controller, components

I have created a component to render basic HTML which its only purpose is to fire a parametrized event when user clicks in it.
As the controller is exactly the same for all of them, I am rendering the HTML based on a specific parameter called componentType.
My concern is about how to get that componentType which is a binding.

```
'use strict'

var app = angular.module('app');
app.component('htmlElement', {
    template: function ($element, $attrs, $log) {        
        if ($attrs.componentType === 'link') {
            return '<a href="#" ng-click="$ctrl.fireEvent();">{{ $ctrl.text }}</a>';
        } else if ($attrs.componentType === 'checkbox') {
            return '<input type="checkbox" ng-click="$ctrl.fireEvent();">{{ $ctrl.text }}';
        }
    },
    bindings: {
        componentType: '<',
        text: '<',
        rowId: '<',
        event: '<'
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.$ctrl.fireEvent = function () {
            $scope.$emit($scope.$ctrl.event, { rowId: $scope.$ctrl.rowId });
        }
    }
});
```

Finally the following line is how I call the component:

```
<html-element ng-if="cell.componentType" component-type="cell.componentType" text="cell.data.text" event="cell.data.event" row-id="cell.data.rowId"></html-element>
```

The problem is that $attrs.componentType gives me the attribute value which is the name of the var so it does not help me at all.
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to evaluate attribute bindings in AngularJS. See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7466.